# How can I check a checkbox in a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I have an application to automate using Selenium-Java where I need to check the checkbox which is inside the Canvas element. The canvas code looks like this:

Can anyone suggest/guide me on how can I click the checkbox?

```html
<canvas id="t1" class="splitcanvas" data-bind="attr:{ width:Controller.TL.Width(), height:Controller.TL.Height(), tabind ex:TLTabIndex()), style: {left:Controller.TL.Left()+'px', top:Controller.TL.Top()+'px', cursor:Controller.TL.Cursor()1, visible: Controller.TL.Visible(), event: {focus: OnFocus}, css: { 'allowFocus': AllowFocus() }" width="500" height="86" tabindex="-1" style="left: Opx; top: Opx; cursor: default; width: 500px; height: 86px;">
```

Comment: Your code has no business down here in a comment. Please put all information in your question post. Also, don't tag your titles.

Comment: i Don't know why he is rejecting formatting as well?

Comment: you can attach picture of your working page, better with html